# Site not working without www

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

My site http://www.fillyo.com is working but if I remove www, it doesn't work.

I'm using A type redirection from my domain panel to my server. I've added entries for both www and non www to the same IP.

[image]

Both records (with and withoud www) point to the same site in IIS.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine from this end.

You might needed to wait a bit for the DNS propagation to take place.

Comment: Really? It's been like 4 days since I added the second redirect. Weird..

Comment: Yep. Have you tried from other locations?

Comment: Its the same for both work and home pc's. I guess it is cached. Tried from another computer and it works. Thank you